# Given binary tree with N nodes and height h.Prove $\lfloor{\log_2(N)}\rfloor\leq h$.

Tags: algorithms, logarithms, trees, binary

Given binary tree with N nodes and height h.Prove $\lfloor{\log_2(N)}\rfloor\leq h$.
I Know that in non empty binary tree: $N \leq 2^{h+1}-1 $
After simple manipulations I get that:
$\log_2(N+1)-1\leq h$
But I cant think of way to prove that $\lfloor{\log_2(N)}\rfloor\leq h$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
N&\le 2^{h+1}-1\\
N&<2^{h+1}\\
\log_2 N&<h+1\\
\lfloor \log_2 N\rfloor&<h+1\\
\lfloor \log_2 N\rfloor&\le h
\end{align}

Comment: I do not get what is the  explanation that \begin{align} \lfloor \log_2 N\rfloor&<h+1\\ \end{align} leads you to the fact that:  \begin{align} \lfloor \log_2 N\rfloor&\le h \end{align}

Comment: Both sides are integers, and so $a<b$ implies $a\le b-1$.

Comment: got it!thanks you