# Structural Induction: Prove that all ternary trees with $n$ vertices have a height of at least $\lfloor\log_{3}{n}\rfloor$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-writing, induction, trees

Prove that all ternary trees (each vertex has up to three children) with $n$ vertices have a height of at least $\lfloor\log_{3}{n}\rfloor$.

I know we can show that a perfect ternary tree of height $h$ has $3^0+3^1+3^2+\dots+3^h=\frac{3^{h+1}-1}{2}$ vertices, $$n=\frac{3^{h+1}-1}{2}$$ so a perfect ternary tree with n vertices must have a height of $$h=\log_{3}{(2n+1)}-1$$
So, imperfect ternary trees have a height of at most $h=\log_{3}{(2n+1)-1}$, and $\lfloor\log_{3}{n}\rfloor\leq \log_{3}{(2n+1)}$, but I need to give a lower bound of $\lfloor\log_{3}{n}\rfloor$.

How should I continue? Or is there a better way to prove this?

Comment: Thank you, I've fixed it.

Comment: See my answer to a very similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3448843/given-binary-tree-with-n-nodes-and-height-h-prove-lfloor-log-2n-rfloor-leq).

Comment: Thank you kindly. Our questions were oddly similar.